# Are there any gameplay differences between Hotline Miami 1 and Hotline Miami 2?

Tags: hotline-miami-2

While I know the storyline is completely different, what I want to know are there any major combat changes in Hotline Miami 2 compared to 1? Having already played Hotline Miami 1, is the combat the same as it was in 1 in 2, or are there any new changes to the formula I should know about before I jump in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some of the gameplay differences I've noticed:

You can take an enemy as a [human shield in HM1](http://hotlinemiami.wikia.com/wiki/Nigel_Lowrie), but not in HM2.

In HM1, if unnoticed, you could run up to an enemy and immediately execute him (<kbd>Space</kbd> in PC) without needing to knock him out first. This can not be done in HM2.

The tiger mask (Tony) in HM1 can pick up and use guns, while the tiger mask and similar melee-only masks or modes in HM2, can not.

There are longer sightlines in HM2 compared to HM1, enemies might be able to shoot you even if you can't see them.